# Links in code dont work when try to click on them?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on a script and trying to add links to submenu items based on bootstrap.
The problem appears when I try to click on them.
They don't work: https://smsverificator.com/2/demo/
Don't know the reason the cannot work here.
I even don't know the language it's written below. Can anybody help me?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../dist/css/flags.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/js/jquery.flagstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://smsverificator.com/assets/css/language_switcher_style.css">
</head>
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select Language</label><br>
                    <div id="options"
                         data-input-name="country2"
                         data-selected-country="US">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

<script>
    $('#basic').flagStrap();
    $('#origin').flagStrap({
        placeholder: {
            value: "",
            text: "Language"
        }
    });
    $('#options')
    .flagStrap({
        countries: {
            "US": '<a target="_self" href="https://smsverificator.com">English</a>',
            "PL": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/pl/">Polish</a>',
            "RU": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/ru/">Russian</a>',
            "DE": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/de/">German</a>',
            "UA": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/ukr/">Ukrainian</a>',
            "ES": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/es/">Spanish</a>',
            "FR": '<a href="https://smsverificator.com/fr/">French</a>',
        },
        buttonSize: "btn-sm",
        buttonType: "btn-info",
        labelMargin: "10px",
        scrollable: false,
        scrollableHeight: "350px"
    });

    $('#advanced')
    .flagStrap({
        buttonSize: "btn-lg",
        buttonType: "btn-primary",
        labelMargin: "20px",
        scrollable: false,
        scrollableHeight: "350px",
        onSelect: function (value, element) {
            alert(value);
            console.log(element);
        }
    });
</script>
        

</body>
</html>
```

How to make them clickable and work?

Comment: Post complete code, not just fragments. There's not enough here to answer the question. Where is the HTML that renders this. From looking at your code it renders a select list. You can't click thru an href from a drop down list.

Comment: It looks like a misuse of the jQuery plugin [flagStrap](https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap). I don't think it's purpose is to create a list of links, it's purpose is to provide a dropdown with countries and flags in the options.

Comment: I added full code of html, any other file is needed?

Comment: here is the link with tip, but i really dont know how and where to use it? https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap/issues/6

Comment: According to that fix, the plugin can render links but you are trying to render a string into HTML. Try the syntax in that example (ie `https://example.com` NOT `<a href="https://example.com"></a>`)

Comment: @zer00ne its not working...

Answer (score 0):

Below is your edited code. I modified your array of countries to put only their names and created a separate table for the urls.
When the user changes the selection, the OnSelect function is triggered.
We then redirect the page to the new url

Make sure the version of flagstrap is the latest. It can be found here: https://github.com/blazeworx/flagstrap/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.flagstrap.min.js

```
   $('#options')
.flagStrap({
    countries: {
        "US": 'English',
        "PL": 'Poland',
        "RU": 'Russian',
        "DE": 'German',
        "UA": 'Ukrainian',
        "ES": 'Spanish',
        "FR": 'French',
    },
    buttonSize: "btn-sm",
    buttonType: "btn-info",
    labelMargin: "10px",
    scrollable: false,
    scrollableHeight: "350px",
    onSelect: function (value, element) {
        let urls = {
        "US": 'https://smsverificator.com',
        "PL": 'https://smsverificator.com/pl/',
        "RU": 'https://smsverificator.com/ru/',
        "DE": 'https://smsverificator.com/de/',
        "UA": 'https://smsverificator.com/ukr/',
        "ES": 'https://smsverificator.com/es/',
        "FR": 'https://smsverificator.com/fr/',
        };
        document.location.href = urls[value];
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```